# Purchasing Single In-App Item from Multiple Account Ambiguity

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

**I am facing a critical edge case on my app**. I will try to explain the situation.

I have an app which offers some premium content via in-app purchase. The user has one email id associated with Play Store on his device.

Here is the scenario:

1) The user logins in to the app using abc@gmail.com and purchases the premium content. This person has never purchased the premium content so his "`isPremiumPurchased` flag is `false`.

The purchase is successful and I grant him the premium content and change the flag to true. **Works as expected.**

2) The user logs out of his account in my app and logs in to my app again using a different account, say xyz@gmail.com. He goes on to purchase the premium content again. This account is a different account so his "`isPremiumPurchased`" flag is `false`.

This user has a separate account from the previous one, right? But if he tries to purchase, **I always get "Item Already Owned"**, which is expected as well. The item was purchased already by another account associated with the same Play Store address, and now this account cannot purchase it.

What should the be ideal way to handle this scenario? I should not allow the second account to have access to the premium content. This is a completely separate account, isn't it? I cannot even consume the item. How can I solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

If you want to differentiate the purchase based on the email used in your app, the purchase must be asociated to the email used to login to your app.  I am not sure, but you can use developerPayload parameter for this.

**Purchase:**

```
iabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(activity, SKU1, RC_REQUEST, purchaseListener, current_email);
```

**Validation:**

```
private boolean validateDeveloperPayload(Purchase purchaseDetails) {
        String payload = purchaseDetails.getDeveloperPayload();
        if(payload.equals(current_email)){
            return true;    
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: The idea is pretty nice here. Let me give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Very Simple. In app Purchases are associated with the primary account in Google Play store.

Say, you have an account myaccount@gmail.com associated to Google Play Store.

> Here is the scenario:
>
> 1) The user logins in to the app using abc@gmail.com and purchases the
>   premium content. This person has never purchased the premium content
>   so his "isPremiumPurchased flag is false.
>
> The purchase is successful and I grant him the premium content and
>   change the flag to true. Works as expected.

The premium content purchase is associated with **myaccount@gmail.com** not with **abc@gmail.com** which is local to your app.

> 2) The user logs out of his account in my app and logs in to my app
>   again using a different account, say xyz@gmail.com. He goes on to
>   purchase the premium content again. This account is a different
>   account so his "isPremiumPurchased" flag is false.
>
> This user has a separate account from the previous one, right? But if
>   he tries to purchase, I always get "Item Already Owned", which is
>   expected as well.

The user logs out from yor app not from the Google Play. Thus when you check the purchse state of premium item, Google play responds you as it is purchased.

> The item was purchased already by another account
>   associated with the same Play Store address, and now this account
>   cannot purchase it.

Please make sure where the account are being switched, is it inside your app or Google accounts?

Here is a small brief;

Download & Install app from playstore with account  '*xxx@gmail.com*', Purchase an item.
Add google accounts in device '*yyy@gmail.com*' in which the item purchase not yet done.
Switch playstore to the account *yyy@gmail.com* and test item.
Item is in PURCHASE state only.

**The account with which the app is downloaded is treated as PRIMARY ACCOUNT to check with purchase details from playstore**

Download & Install app from playstore with account  '*xxx@gmail.com*', Purchase an item.
Add google accounts in device '*yyy@gmail.com*' in which the item purchase not yet done.
Switch playstore to the account *yyy@gmail.com* and test item.
Item is in **PURCHASE** state only.
Remove account, *xxx@gmail.com* from the device, and check the item. 
Item is in **UNPURCHASED** state.

**Since '*xxx@gmail.com*' is removed, primary account is '*yyy@gmail.com*'.
Now the IN APP ITEMS  for '*yyy@gmail.com*' are not purchased.**

Comment: You didn't understand my problem correctly. Please read the question again.